# Помогите составить SQL запрос где в WHERE будет 2 раза "AND"

Tags: sql, запрос, where

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со свиду простым sql запросом, но который не работает, уже все варианты испробовал и через дополнительные joinы и через вариации в WHERE.

Таблица User

| id | status | postId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | new | 55555 |
| 23456 | ready | 55555 |
| 34567 | done | 77777 |

Нужно вывести postId если у него есть status = new **И** status = ready.
Должен вывестись postId = 55555

Мой вариант:

```
SELECT
       postId
FROM User
WHERE postId IN (55555, 77777)
AND (status = new AND status = ready)
GROUP BY postId
```

Но он не работает из-за противоречия (status = new AND status = ready), работает только (status = new OR status = ready), но мне не подходит такое условие, нужно чтобы строго и new и ready было.
MySql.

Comment: Какая используется СУБД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так?

```
    SELECT postId FROM User WHERE status = ready AND postId IN 
    (SELECT postId FROM User WHERE status = new )
```

Я писал из головы, так что возможны некоторые лёгонькие ошибки синтаксиса (так, например, в боевой базе наверняка `status = 'ready'` - что то в таком духе)

Comment: @Robokop А что не сработало? как вы описали задачу, этот ответ должен работать

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо! Утром на свежую голову все заработало. Но видимо без вложенного запроса никак не обойтись?

Comment: Просто в случае если нужна будет проверка по 3 статусам, то будет подзапрос в под запросе, а если 4-5-6-7 статусов, то вообще что то нереальное выйдет.